# Repetition when scraping using rvest in R

Tags: r, rvest

I am trying to scrape text using rvest in R and df1 is the output. For News 2, the text was spilt into 3 rows and this causes News 1 to repeat for 2 more extra rows. How can I make News 2 join into 1 complete sentence?

```
> dput(df1)
  structure(list(`News 1` = c("Nike faces social media storm in China over Xinjiang statement", 
  "Nike faces social media storm in China over Xinjiang statement", 
  "Nike faces social media storm in China over Xinjiang statement"
  ), `News 2` = c("Biden calls for assault weapon ban after", "Colorado", 
  "shooting")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
  "data.frame"))
```

My desired output is having the whole sentence in the same row

```
 df1 >
    News 1                                             News 2                                                 
 1  Nike faces social media storm in China over        Biden calls for assault weapon ban 
    Xinjiang statement                                 after Colorado shooting
```

Comment: You'd probably need to include some more sample data. I'm just guessing News 1 and News 2 columns will contain more than one title. Is it the case? Also, are there any other columns present? Like e.g. columns indexing parts of split sentences.

Comment: It looks like you have some stray newline characters (\n) confusing things. Without seeing your code it's hard to say, but you could try piping stringr::str_squish() after the html_text() line in your code, and see if that helps.